# Share production files with colleagues securely

Tags: matrix, forecasting, collaboration

I am wanting to share some files, collaborate between friends, and work on projects together  **securely** but I am unsure on what to use.  I've debated on Drop Box but there is no way to reliably communicate what is being done or who is doing what.  Another option to add would be using Google docs but it would be a headache bouncing back and forth.  Does a full solution exist to allow project communication privately that can allow matrix or forecasting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org), it's a control version tool. This will provide you an interface to see what has been done and who has done it, and simply looking at the web page of your bitbucket project.

Also, the only requisite is to have an internet access, since you can get a private repo without any cost (there are other tools like Github, but the project must be opensource in order to use it for free).

If you decide for this option, consider creating a team for you and your friends, this will allow you to:

-Create team-owned repos that everyone can access

-Delegate administration to manage members and repositories

-Set up groups to quickly organize members and their privilege levels

-Send invitations to new team members, whether they are on Bitbucket or not